# How to make the User's Control's BackGround transparent?

Tags: c#, user-controls, background, parent, transparent

I want my UserControl's BackGround to look like it's not there. I tried to do it like that:

```
if ((Parent != null) && (Parent.BackgroundImage != null))
{
    Bitmap backGroundImage = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
    Graphics.FromImage(backGroundImage).DrawImage(owner.BackgroundImage, 0, 0, new Rectangle(Location.X, Location.Y, Width, Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
     this.BackgroundImage = (Image)backGroundImage;
}
```

and it works, but I also have to calculate BackGroundImage of the Form which is UserControl's Parent every time its size changes and set Form's BackGroundImageLayout to none. My UserControl could take Parent's BackGroundImage and stretch it every time it needs to redraw, and then just take a piece of it and set it as its BackGroundImage, but Form draws its stretched background outside its visible rectangle. So I can see then the diffrence, it doesn't fit.

I made it working and it fits the Parent's BackGroundImage, but it's a lot of code and slowing down my program when resizing.

There must be a simplest way to do that. I don't mean using ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor. I want it to look just like there were no UserControl's background.

Comment: You copying background image piece(size of your control) from parent form and setting that piece as control background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make usercontrol backcolor as Transparent  `this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use , someUserControl.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Transparent); and invisible BackColor.

Comment: @Nighil, @hashi: It works and saved me a lot of work :) If you could also tell me, if it's possible, can I set the BackColor of Control which Parent is UserControl, which Parent if Form to transparent, when UserControl's BackColor isn't transparent?

I tried to set Form as Control's Parent, and then set its BackGround Color as transparent, but it doesn't work...

Comment: and also another thing: when I set to transparent BackColor of Control, which Parent is UserControl, which Parent is Form, and UserControl's BackColor is also Transparent, then my program stops working, nothing happens, no errors or exceptions.

Comment: You should edit your original post. No one will understand what you mean by "invisible/no background" What you are looking for is "transparency" and "ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor" plus BackColor to Transparent is in fact the simplest way to *approximate* this for a UserControl.  Select an answer and close this question - your original question has been answered.  For Controls the above no longer works reliably, panels and a few others maybe but...  Search "Transparent Winforms Controls".  Every variation and known hacks of this topic under the sun has already been asked/answered.

Comment: I don't know how to close it.

Comment: Sorry, "close" is not really the right terminology.  In general a question should cover one specific item, once you have a working answer, you should select the answer you think is best, or add your own, so others know the question has been resolved.  Additional questions in comments should be limited to clarification of a specific answer.  If an answer leads to another question, i.e.  how to make control backgrounds transparent, research/possibly ask that as new question.  You are working towards some specific solution. Multiple questions that seem related to you may not be for other people.

Answer (score 1):

> if you need parent is transparent you
>   can use this code :

```
 parent.BackColor = Color.Red;
 parent.TransparencyKey = parent.BackColor;
```